# What's a preferred way now to bulk upload images to Flickr?

Tags: software-recommendation, photo-management, flickr

preferably no Java or Mono

Comment: [Community Wikified](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/67/why-do-some-questions-have-community-wiki-over-the-users-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[shotwell](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shotwell) (10.10+) and [f-spot](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/f-spot)  (10.04 and below) both have the ability to export in bulk to Flickr.

Comment: f-spot uses Mono.

Comment: Shotwell ain't working for me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42063/shotwell-refusing-to-publish-more-than-one-photo-at-a-time

Answer (score 2):

Desktop Flickr Organizer is good.

For GNOME.

[image]

**Benefits: It's a standalone, single-purpose application**, if you don't want to use Shotwell for actually organizing your photos.

Link to project Google Code page:  [Desktop Flickr Organizer](http://code.google.com/p/dfo/)

Answer (score 1):

I tried [Postr](http://projects.gnome.org/postr/) and [Frogr](http://live.gnome.org/Frogr), both have the basic functionality to bulk upload, give titles, description, tags, assign sets and groups.

Answer (score 0):

Postr works well.  I have also used kFlickr.