# Shotwell refusing to publish more than one photo at a time

Tags: 11.04, photo-management, shotwell, flickr

I'm using Shotwell 0.9.2 on Ubuntu 11.04. If I select 5 photos, click **Publish**, and then **Publish** again I get a message saying:

> Uploading 1 of 5

However, once the progress bar gets to the end it still reads "1 of 5" and the operation completes at that point, saying:

> The selected photos were successfully
>   published.

But only the first one in my selection is ever published!

This seems like a rather obvious bug to have been missed. Does anyone have any information or a workaround for this? Couldn't find anything obvious with google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this reproduce every time?

This is the first time I've heard of this issue.  Could you do us a huge favor and file a ticket on this?
http://trac.yorba.org/newticket

Also, we have a wiki page on how you can collect data for us that would help solve this bug.
http://trac.yorba.org/wiki/Shotwell/FAQ#IfoundabuginShotwell.HowcanIreportit

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, every time thus far for me. I'll log a ticket asap. Thanks for the links.

Comment: OK, ticket created: http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/3598

Comment: Thanks again for finding this.  The fix is already in master, and will be in Shotwell 0.10.

Comment: If anyone is curious about the change: http://git.yorba.org/cgit.cgi/shotwell/commit/?id=de6cd133d6bf230e4ad03489ff72ca1fbc54a469

Comment: Tried this the other day in 0.10 with a set of photos I had scanned and manually set a date/time on. Worked a treat. Many thanks for fixing this so quickly.